# Openstack - File system changing to read-only mode after 1 or 2 days of creating the instance. Not able to access any files after that

Tags: filesystems, openstack, openstack-swift

Openstack - File system changing to read-only mode after 1 or 2 days of creating the instance. Not able to access any files after that. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 instances. I have installed openstack on my server which is also ubuntu 18.04. I have enough disk space. After this issues, when i try to remount , i am not able to do. what is the cause of this kind of issue and how to resolve this. Kindly help me in resolving this. Attaching log here:

```
[Recent Log - Part1][1]
[Recent Log - Part2][2] 
[dmesg-log][3] 
[syslog][4]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISbKl.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Ekg.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Cy8.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf3WM.jpg
```

Comment: The errors you posted are just the result of the read-only filesystem, have you checked the instance's `dmesg` and `syslog` entries? There should be at least some pointer to the root cause.

Comment: @eblock i have included the dmesg and syslogs with error and failed state. kindly let me know what is the issue and how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

According to dmesg log the disk is corrupted (`I/O error dev vda`), and fsck doesn't seem to be able to correct the errors, and they're reappearing. If this instances is critical you should mount it read-only and try to save as much data as possible. You could also try to copy the disk with `ddrescue` to a different device.

Comment: What might me the possible reasons for the disk to be corrupted?

Comment: There are several possibilties, hard to say. It could be the underlying storage device or array (what is your backend?), power outage, code bugs, etc. I would probably look into the storage backend first, then compute nodes in `/var/log/nova/`.

Answer (score 0):

Instance turns into Read Only file system and no files whatsoever can be edited, deleted or created

I cloned a volume of an instance, create snapshot -> create new volume -> launch new instance.
It turned out to be the case that both existing and new instance became Read-Only.

Logon to the affected instance(s) and run fsck command for the mounted disks mapped in fstab.

$ sudo cat /etc/fstab

*/etc/fstab: static file system information.
Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
               
/ was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-do30PLgpOVFMSMdAM4yk61c90yuy3biE4jAn171mXyGByntK0sddMxpZRL1WLPmq / ext4 defaults 0 0
/boot was on /dev/vda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1b94eedc-be13-45b6-b7c1-f9892b69296e /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0*

As you can notice the logical volume is mounted on root drive /
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-do30PLgpOVFMSMdAM4yk61c90yuy3biE4jAn171mXyGByntK0sddMxpZRL1WLPmq /

Therefore, run fsck command to fix

$ sudo fsck /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-do30PLgpOVFMSMdAM4yk61c90yuy3biE4jAn171mXyGByntK0sddMxpZRL1WLPmq

*

> fsck from util-linux 2.34 e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv contains a file system with errors,
> check forced. Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes Deleted inode
> 400138 has zero dtime.  Fix? yes Inodes that were part of a
> corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? yes Inode 400139 was part
> of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED. Inode 400140 was part of the
> orphaned inode list.  FIXED. Inode 400141 was part of the orphaned
> inode list.  FIXED. Inode 400142 was part of the orphaned inode list.
> FIXED. Inode 400333 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED. Inode
> 420207 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED. Pass 2: Checking
> directory structure Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity Pass 4:
> Checking reference counts Pass 5: Checking group summary information
> Block bitmap differences:  -(397395--397407) -3850237
> -(3852815--3852822) Fix? yes Free blocks count wrong for group #12 (15295, counted=15308). Fix? yes Free blocks count wrong for group
> #117 (5588, counted=5597). Fix? yes Free blocks count wrong (1462405, counted=1462427). Fix? yes Inode bitmap differences:
> -(400138--400142) -400333 -420207 Fix? yes Free inodes count wrong for group #48 (0, counted=6). Fix? yes Free inodes count wrong for
> group #51 (27, counted=28). Fix? yes Free inodes count wrong
> (935590, counted=935597). Fix ('a' enables 'yes' to all) ? yes
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED
> ***** /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: ***** REBOOT SYSTEM ***** /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 309587/1245184 files (0.2%
> non-contiguous), 3517285/4979712 blocks

- 

$ sudo reboot

All looks normal now.
Thereafter extend volume from openstack to test further
pvresize works
vgextend works
lvextend works
resize2fs works